# Какие серьезные программы для SEO и html анализа сайта существуют?

Tags: seo, html

Пробовал semonitor , e`rida. Gsitecrawler.

Интересует

1. Проверка битых ссылок
2. Формирование полной карты сайта (чтобы прошла вообще по всем ссылкам, а не только по первым уровням вложенности) и показала красивый вывод, а не просто записала на диск xml txt файл.
3. Анализ ключевых слов. То есть подробное рассмотрение для каждой страницы и для всего сайта. В идеале, если программа также сделает запросы по поисковым системам и посмотрит какой популярностью пользуются присутствующие ключевые слова.
4. Желательно встроенный валидатор по коду, для всех страниц.
5. Желательно бесплатная.

Comment: да таких халяв нет :)

Comment: ну а платных?

Answer (score 1):

Есть Магадан и есть Магадан PRO, semonitor да, еще был такой СловоЁБ, twidium для твиттера.
Чекеров ссылок масса всяких в инете, я бы порекомендовал еще а/б тесты посмотреть программы

Answer (score 1):

1. Xenu Links -  классика, NetPeak Spider